# Could not find method apt()

Tags: android, dagger-2, apt

I'm trying to work with Dagger2, I am using Android studio 2.2.2
but I have an error with gradle:

```
Error:(34, 0) Could not find method apt() for arguments
[com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6] on object of type
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\edi.bershatsky\Google
Drive\Android\eWave\MyCode\MyDagger2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

please help me to understand what is wrong with my gradle

this is my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my module gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.edi.mydagger2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

ext {
    JUNIT_VERSION = '4.12'
    DAGGER_VERSION ='2.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6'
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Add

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6"
```

inside dependencies

NOTE:

> With android gradle plugin 2.2.0 release, the android-apt plugin is no longer needed for annotation processing. The apt function was included in the latest android gradle plugin which called annotationProcessor.

Comment: The annotationProcessor solved my problem
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 9):

Use annotationProcessor instead of apt

Answer (score 4):

use

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.19"
```

in your dependencies instead of

```
 compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19'
 apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.19'
```

Comment: prefer to use latest version of dagger

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually apply android-apt plugin

```
 apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

(but now you should just remove it and use `annotationProcessor` or `kapt` with `kotlin-kapt` depending on your language anyways)

Comment: android-apt plugin is depreceated

Answer (score 0):

`annotationProcessor` cannot work if you haven't enabled the option in Android Studio. To do so :

Close your project, click on **Configure** at the bottom right, then **Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Compiler** > **Annotation Processors** and tick ***enable annotation processing***.

Then you can use `annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:X.X"`